How many Boundary and initial conditions are needed for nonlinear coupled PDEs? Is there a theorem?
I would like to solve the following coupled PDEs, and I wonder how many initial and boundary conditions I need.
$$ \partial_t z(x,t) + \partial_x (z(x,t) b(x,t))=0  $$
$$ \partial_x (z(x,t) |b_x|^{m-1} b_x)=0$$
I read about the number of BCs and initial conditions needed for solving PDEs, and think that one needs one initial condition for $b(x,t)$ and one initial condition for $z(x,t)$ as the equations are first order in time. Since $b(x,t)$ has a $2$nd order derivative with respect to $x$, I need two boundary conditions for $b(x,t)$. Since the highest order x derivative with respect to $z(x,t)$ is one, I think I need one boundary condition for $z(x,t)$.
However, I am unsure because the second equation has $|\partial_x b|^{m-1}$. Could someone please guide me on how many boundaries and initial conditions I need?
If anyone knows the number of boundaries and initial conditions cannot be specified, that information would also be helpful.

no time derivative of $b$, that's right. But to solve the equations, don't I need an initial form for b that satisfies the second equation? @whpowell96
